# Exportar Tablas de una BD a un Excel con una hoja por tabla

Tags: java, sql, excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola señores, estoy buscando **Exportar las Tablas de una BD** *(Da igual el motor, me importa que se pueda)* **a un Excel con una hoja por tabla**.

Ejemplo: un solo archivo llamado *gastos.csv* que dentro contenga una hoja por cada tabla que exista en la BD, una hoja llamada cliente, otra hoja llamada producto, otra hoja llamada Proyectos y así cada uno por separado con todos sus registros. Pero todo en un solo archivo.

¿Se entiende?, sé que se puede exportar a excel pero no si se puede crear más de una hoja directo desde la BD.

Trabajo con el lenguaje **Java** específicamente con la librería swing, no sé si tenga relevancia.

¡Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]